# Count number of 2 consecutive negative values in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Per the title I want to count the number of times 2 consecutive negative values exist in a series of returns.

To illustrate, the formula should return 2 given the series

```
0, -1, 3, -2, -1, -4, 5, -6
```

and should return 1 given the series

```
0, -1, 3, -2, -1, 5, -6
```

Comment: do you need it on excel build-in function? or you are open to making a custom function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS with staggered ranges:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A8,"<0",A3:A9,"<0")
```

[image]

Change the `,` to `;` if needed based on your Excel version.

Comment: Thank you. Since I am using table ranges I changed it to `=COUNTIFS(Table1[return],"<0",OFFSET(Table1[return],1,0),"<0")`